# please help me with the test class of this part of controller class

Tags: apex, code-coverage

**Part of controller class**

```
 global class ApexSchedulerCreateSearchescl {
      static List<RecordType> listrt;
      static String zipcode;
      static ID state;
      static string sPortalParent { get; set;}
      static string sRecordTypeId{get; set;}
      static RecordType DegreeRecordType;
      static RecordType ReferenceRecordType;
      static RecordType DOTVerRecordType;
      static RecordType EmploymentRecordType;
      static RecordType LicenseRecordType;
      static RecordType PendingRecordType;
      public static List<BGC_Reference_Intake__c> lstBGCReferenceIntake{get;set;}
      public static List<BGC_License_Intake__c> lstBGCLicenseIntake{get;set;}
      public static List<BGC_Degree_Intake__c> lstBGCDegreeIntake{get;set;}
      public static List<BGC_Employment_Intakes__c> lstBGCEmploymentIntake{get;set;}
      public static List<BGC_DOT_Intake__c> lstBGCDOTIntake{get;set;}
      webService static string CreateSearches() {
        string sStatus = 'Start Execution: ';
        try {
          PreEmployCasecl oPreEmployCasecl = new PreEmployCasecl();
          SearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate__c oSearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate = [SELECT Id, days__c  FROM SearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate__c];
          integer iNoofDays = -7;
        if(oSearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate != null){ 
              iNoofDays = integer.valueof(oSearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate.days__c.intvalue());
            }
          List<PreEmploy_Case__c> LstCase = [SELECT Id, Name, People_Controller__c, Formation_Order_Request_Date__c, Subject_First_Name__c, Package_ID__c,
          Order_Number__c, Subject_of_background__c, Subject_Last_Name__c, Subject_Middle_Name__c, DL_or_ID_State__c, Account__c, County__c,
          Report_Case_Status__c, RecordType.Name FROM PreEmploy_Case__c WHERE createddate > : datetime.now().adddays(iNoofDays) AND createddate < : datetime.now().addMinutes(-3) AND
          Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation' AND Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true AND 
          Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true AND Order_Number__c != null ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1];
          if(test.isRunningTest()) {
            LstCase = [SELECT Id, Name, People_Controller__c, Formation_Order_Request_Date__c, Subject_First_Name__c,
            Order_Number__c, Subject_of_background__c, Subject_Last_Name__c, Subject_Middle_Name__c, DL_or_ID_State__c, Account__c, County__c,
            Report_Case_Status__c, RecordType.Name FROM PreEmploy_Case__c WHERE Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation' AND Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true AND Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true LIMIT 1];
          }
          system.debug(LstCase.size());
          if(LstCase.size() > 0) {        <----------------
            ApexSchedulerCreateSearchescl.SetRecordType();
            sRecordTypeId = PendingRecordType.Id;
```

**inspite of my all effort i am not able to cover the code beyond Marked Line (Line after system.debug()).
I also used test.isRunningTest() but not getting LstCase.size() above 0.**

My test class method

```
@isTest
private class ApexSchedulerCreateSearchescl_TEST{

  static testmethod void TestApexSchedulerCreateSearches(){
    test.startTest();
    account acc= new account(Name = 'testtng');
    insert acc;  
    Country__c oCountry = new Country__c(Name = 'United States');
    insert oCountry;
    Country__c oCountry1 = new Country__c(Name = 'Canada');
    insert oCountry1;
    SearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate__c oSearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate = new SearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate__c(name ='testing',days__c = -7);
    insert oSearchAutomationCaseLastCreatedDate;
    State_Providence__c pcSP = new State_Providence__c(Name='test', Abbreviation__c = 'te');
    insert pcSP;
    Contact pcContact = new Contact(LastName = 'tester', FirstName = 'test');
    insert pcContact;
    People_Controller__c pcPC = new People_Controller__c(Contact__c = pcContact.id);
    insert pcPC; 
    Background_Check_Service_Package__c bcsp = new Background_Check_Service_Package__c(HISTORIC_Package_Code__c = 'testing');
    insert bcsp;
    BGC_Order__c bo = new BGC_Order__c(Subject_has_Multiple_Names__c = true, Subject_Zip_Code__c = '95256', State_Providence__c = pcSP.Id, Account__c = acc.id, BGC_Service_Package__c = bcsp.id);
    insert bo;
    BGC_List_of_Services__c oBGCService2 = new BGC_List_of_Services__c(name = 'Education Verification', Run_AKA_s__c = true);
    insert oBGCService2;
    BGC_List_of_Services__c oBGCService3 = new BGC_List_of_Services__c(name = 'International Degree Verification', Run_AKA_s__c = true);
    insert oBGCService3;
    BGC_S_O_Individual__c bsoi1 = new BGC_S_O_Individual__c(Selected_Service__c = oBGCService2.id,Package__c = true, a_la_carte__c = true,Quantity__c = '3', Unlimited__c = true,
    BGC_Order__c = bo.id, Historic_Search_No__c = '1232', Minimum_Quantity__c = '2');
    insert bsoi1;
    PreEmploy_Case__c pc1 = new PreEmploy_Case__c(Formation_Order_Request_Date__c = system.now().date(), Report_Case_Status__c = 'Approved to Start', Subject_of_background__c = pcContact.Id, Order_Number__c = bo.id, Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true, Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true, People_Controller__c = pcPC.id);
    insert pc1; 
    BGC_Degree_Intake__c oBGCDegree = new BGC_Degree_Intake__c(Background_Check_Order__c = pc1.Order_Number__c, Service_Ordered__c =bsoi1.id , School_Country__c = oCountry.id) ;
    insert oBGCDegree;
    BGC_Degree_Intake__c oBGCDegree2 = new BGC_Degree_Intake__c(Background_Check_Order__c = pc1.Order_Number__c, Service_Ordered__c =bsoi1.id , School_Country__c = null) ;
    insert oBGCDegree2;
    List<PreEmploy_Case__c> LstCase = [SELECT Id, Name, People_Controller__c, Formation_Order_Request_Date__c, Subject_First_Name__c, Order_Number__c, Subject_of_background__c, Subject_Last_Name__c, Subject_Middle_Name__c, DL_or_ID_State__c, Account__c, County__c, Report_Case_Status__c, RecordType.Name FROM PreEmploy_Case__c WHERE Id = :pc1.id AND createddate > : datetime.now().adddays(-4) AND Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation' AND Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true AND Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true AND Order_Number__c != null ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1];    
    ApexSchedulerCreateSearchescl.CreateSearches();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this below code,

```
LstCase = [SELECT Id, Name, People_Controller__c, Formation_Order_Request_Date__c, Subject_First_Name__c,
            Order_Number__c, Subject_of_background__c, Subject_Last_Name__c, Subject_Middle_Name__c, DL_or_ID_State__c, Account__c, County__c,
            Report_Case_Status__c, RecordType.Name FROM PreEmploy_Case__c WHERE Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation' AND Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true AND Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true LIMIT 1];
```

You are inserting `PreEmploy_Case__c` record in test class with `Report_Case_Status__c's` value as **'Approved to Start'** whereas as per above query it should be **'Pending Automation'**. That is the reason, you are not getting any records in the SOQL. So, either insert `PreEmploy_Case__c` with `Report_Case_Status__c` value as **'Pending Automation'** or update the record so that status is **'Pending Automation'**

Replace below code is test class

```
PreEmploy_Case__c pc1 = new PreEmploy_Case__c(Formation_Order_Request_Date__c = system.now().date(), Report_Case_Status__c = 'Approved to Start', Subject_of_background__c = pcContact.Id, Order_Number__c = bo.id, Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true, Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true, People_Controller__c = pcPC.id);
insert pc1;
```

with

```
PreEmploy_Case__c pc1 = new PreEmploy_Case__c(Formation_Order_Request_Date__c = system.now().date(), Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation', Subject_of_background__c = pcContact.Id, Order_Number__c = bo.id, Is_Searches_Creation_Pending__c = true, Subject_Information_Searches_Created__c = true, People_Controller__c = pcPC.id);
insert pc1;
```

or add this below code after insert

```
pc1.Report_Case_Status__c = 'Pending Automation';
update pc1;
```

Comment: Still Not covering

Comment: Do you have any workflow/PB/flows/triggers on `PreEmploy_Case__c` which are updating its fields ? And what is the value, you are getting for `system.debug(LstCase.size())` ?

Comment: Thanks @Vijay on inserting Report_Case_Status__c with 'Pending Automation' is not working but after insert and then update it is working.